# JTAG instruction register length, IR_LEN

Tags: debugging, arduino, arm, embedded, jtag

I need to specify user configuration settings for [JTAGenum](https://github.com/cyphunk/JTAGenum/blob/master/JTAGenum.ino) Jtag enumeration utility.
In particular, in this part

```
// Target specific, check your documentation or guess 
#define SCAN_LEN                 1890 // used for IR enum. bigger the better
#define IR_LEN                   5
// IR registers must be IR_LEN wide:
#define IR_IDCODE                "01100" // always 011
#define IR_SAMPLE                "10100" // always 101
#define IR_PRELOAD IR_SAMPLE
```

In the user [manual](https://github.com/cyphunk/JTAGenum/) noted that IR_LEN defines the length of the JTAG instruction register. `"If you change this you should also add ‘0’s to each of the corresponding IR_** instruction definitions."`

JTAG Instruction Register (IR) length for the target CPU is 4 bits.
So I set IR_LEN = 4.

Not clear if I should change also `#define IR_IDCODE` and `#define IR_PRELOAD` values, and where should be added mentioned "‘0’s to each of the corresponding IR_** instruction definitions."

Comment: Whoever voted this an off-topic usage question did so in error.  JTAG in this context is a key *development tool* generally used to load and debug embedded software, and development tool questions are the explicitly on-topic exception to the usual policy on usage questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your starting point has a register length of 5 and shows five bit codes.

In keeping with your quoted instruction, it would appear that when adapting this for a device with a 4 bit register, you should *shorten* these codes to four bits, by removing the final zero from each.

ie

```
#define IR_LEN                   4
// IR registers must be IR_LEN wide:
#define IR_IDCODE                "0110" // always 011
#define IR_SAMPLE                "1010" // always 101
```